# Calculate road density within buffers in R

Tags: r, buffer, density

I am running the following code to calculate road density within buffers, first I thought It was working great, but then did a few reality checks, where the code has given more than 1 as density and it became obvious that those buffers sometimes even don't contain any roads. This could have been driven because of a wrong coordinate system, but as you can see I projected them first. I used OSMDataset for roads, might be that something is wrong with that as well.

this what my data looks like:

[image]

These are codes:

```
# Read in the shapefile containing the roads data
roads <- st_read("C:..//maps//pennsylvania-latest-free.shp//gis_osm_roads_free_1.shp")

# Filter out the "track" road type
roads <- roads[!(roads$fclass %in% c("track", "track_grade1", "track_grade2", "track_grade3", "track_grade4", "track_grade5", "steps")), ]

# Read in the CSV file containing the buffer points
points <- read.csv("card_xy_zone17 _ Copy.csv")

# Convert the points to an sf object with WGS84 coordinates
points_sf <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

# Project the points to NAD 1983 UTM Zone 17N
points_utm <- st_transform(points_sf, 26917)

# Buffer the points by 150 meters
buffers <- st_buffer(points_utm, dist = 1000)

# Project the buffers to NAD 1983 UTM Zone 17N
buffers_utm <- st_transform(buffers, 26917)

# Project the roads to NAD 1983 UTM Zone 17N
roads_utm <- st_transform(roads, 26917)

# Check the CRS of the roads and buffers
st_crs(roads_utm)
st_crs(buffers_utm)
nrow(buffers_utm)
st_crs(buffers)

# Plot the roads and buffers
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = roads_utm, fill = NA, color = "blue") +
  geom_sf(data = buffers_utm, fill = NA, color = "red") +
  theme_void()

# Extract the buffer and roads that intersect it and calculate the density of roads
densities <- numeric(length = nrow(buffers_utm))

roads_intersect <- st_intersection(roads_utm, buffers)
roads_intersect$length <- st_length(roads_intersect)

roads_aggregate <- aggregate(roads_intersect$length, by = list(roads_intersect$card), FUN = sum)
head(roads_aggregate)
colnames(roads_aggregate) <- c('card', 'length')

st_length(roads_intersect)
summary(roads_aggregate)

buffer_area <- st_area(buffers)
head(buffer_area)
head(buffers)
buffers$area <- buffer_area/10000


buffers_merge <- merge(buffers, roads_aggregate, by = 'card', all = TRUE)


buffers$density <- buffer_area/10000

buffers_merge$length <-  buffers_merge$length / 1000

head(buffers_merge)

summary(buffers_merge)

buffers_merge$length[is.na(buffers_merge$length)] <- 0

buffers_merge$road_density <- buffers_merge$length/buffers_merge$area

# Select columns from buffers_merge
card  <- buffers_merge$card 

buffer_id <- buffers_merge$buffer_id
area <- buffers_merge$area
length <- buffers_merge$length
road_density <- buffers_merge$road_density

# Create a new data frame
new_df <- data.frame(card, buffer_id, area, length, road_density)

# Write data frame to CSV file
write.csv(new_df, 'road_density_1000.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? What's not "consistent"? What's "complicated and messy" about the CSV output? Is it because you have lines output and you are expecting points? Have you tried it on a small subset of the data and checked the stages to see if its doing what you expect?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback, I edited the code above and solved the problem, but now problem is that I am not any more confident that density is calculated correctly, any help would be appreciated